# Error copying data to new Excel sheet using a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post here.

I am trying to copy data from one sheet to a new sheet in the same workbook after filtering in the main sheet.

I also have to copy the sheet template from a template sheet onto this new sheet where I am copying the data to before I copy the data.

This is the VBA code shown in my macro:

```
Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Rows("1:3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Dim sSheetName As String
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    sSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("N13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sSheetName").Select
    Range("D4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sSheetName").Select
    Range("C4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sSheetName").Select
    Range("E4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sSheetName").Select
    Range("F4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("H13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sSheetName").Select
    Range("G4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("F13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sSheetName").Select
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Fives Cinetic Corp"
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 17.57
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A4:A5")
    Range("A4:A5").Select
    Range("D10").Select
End Sub
```

I get an error: Run-time Error 9:  Subscript out of range

Guess its something to do with sheet numbers but not able to figure it out exactly what it is.

Comment: It's always good practice to avoid using certain unreliable functions such as `.select` and `.copy`/`.paste`. I'd advise looking up alternative methods and rewriting your code. Also have a look at the tour and read up on how to ask a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hi Josh,Thanks for the tip. I shall practice what you have suggested in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase you haven't solved this already, take a look at the code I've adapted for you. When making new VBA projects, play around with some of these methods, you'll find they're a lot faster and more reliable than your previous version. Compare them side by side.

This took a lot of assumption on my part so make a backup before running this to test it and make sure everything is going to the right place.

```
Sub Macro7()

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    NewSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets("Template").Rows("1:3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("N13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(NewSheet).Range("D4")

    With Sheets(NewSheet)
        Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    Range("A13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(NewSheet).Range("C4")

    Range("D13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(NewSheet).Range("E4")

    Range("B13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(NewSheet).Range("F4")

    Range("H13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(NewSheet).Range("G4")

    Range("F13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(NewSheet).Range("I4")

    Sheets(NewSheet).Activate
    Range("A4").Value = "Fives Cinetic Corp"
    Columns("A:A").AutoFit
    Range("A4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A4:A5")
    Range("D10").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Josh,I understand my knowledge of VBA is at its very basic now that I see your code.
Your's looks more structured and easier to understand and edit. Thank you for taking your time out and helping me out in this en-devour.

Comment: I would like to know why you have given D13, N13 etc in Range? I am getting a #Ref error in the D4 range in the new sheet.  Reswt of the code works flawlessly

Comment: I just picked out the ranges you had selected in your code, is the code putting a formula in D4? If so, it might be the way the formula was made to work originally. For example, if the formula says "Sum of A1 and B1" and you then moved it to a new sheet where there wasn't a value in B1, you would get an error.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Figured it out. Minor changes were required. Its reduced my work to a good extent. Also, do you know of any VBA tutorials or courses that I can go through to improve my VBA skills?

Comment: Unfortunately, since VBA has a sort of built in UI (Excel), it's quite tricky. The best way to learn any language is with practice, things like this :) Maybe find a good book to teach you the fundamentals, but nothing beats doing things you don't know how to do.